# Enable AHCI on dual boot system Win 10 and Win XP

Tags: boot, ssd

Actually both Win 10 and XP are installed in dual boot on same SSD and run fine in IDE mode. For better performance, I want to switch from IDE to AHCI. If I first switch Win 10 to AHCI, Win 10 runs fine, but Win XP won't boot anymore. And if I first switch XP to AHCI, Win 10 won't boot. How can i switch both Win 10 and XP to AHCI ? Thanks for help.

Comment: One doesn’t switch between IDE and AHCI without proper drivers and your unlikely to find compatible AHCI drivers for Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

> How can i switch both Win 10 and XP to AHCI ?

That will not likely work .   XP is just too old for running properly on new systems.

Set up Windows 10 properly and then make XP a Virtual Machine inside Windows 10.

That will work for sure - I have XP running fine in a VM - Windows 10 then and Windows 11 now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Problem is that when Win 10 is set in AHCI in BIOS, Win XP won't boot. I have the AHCI driver for XP, but don't know how to install it in order to be able to boot to XP and to Win 10 in AHCI mode.

Comment: You will need to run XP in a virtual machine to co-exist with Windows 10 / 11 . I do that.